# How do people watch for new questions on Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, answers

I'm curious as to how my questions seem to get answered so quickly on Stack Overflow!

How do people watch for new questions on the Stack Exchange sites? Is there some sort of desktop widget which can automatically notify you on new questions?

Answer (score 7):

There is an [RSS feed](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds), but mostly I just use the browser's refresh button.

Answer (score 6):

Click [image]many times until an interesting question appears.

Comment: Absolutely not - that takes you to the home page which doesn't have the most appropriate sort order. You click on "Questions" a lot, having previously clicked on the "Newest" tab.

Comment: @Jon: Sometimes I click Unanswered too, but Questions never give me better results than the front page or Unanswered.

Comment: That depends on your meaning of "better". If you're trying to watch for new questions (as per the question here) then using "Questions" certainly *does* give you better results.

Answer (score 1):

You just go to the main page, find a question that interests you, answer it, go back to the main page (by now there will be new questions on the main page), repeat.

or you can follow tags, which have an RSS feed.

Answer (score 0):

There is also [filters](https://stackexchange.com/filters), which allow you to aggregate multiple tags across multiple sites, so you have an overview of all and only the recent questions that are potentially interesting. However, I'm not sure how many people actually use this feature (I do).